# Add or modify workflow Reasons in Devops Azure Workitems

Tags: azure-devops, workitem, azure-devops-extensions

Presently I am using Devops Azure (Cloud). 
For Work items is there a way to add and modify workflow Reasons.

[State and Reason change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmO6I.png)

I am looking to add some custom reasons in the work item for each State.

Is there a way to change these. From the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops), its mentioned, "You can add and remove workflow States. However, you can't add or modify workflow Reasons.". Any pointers to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking to add some custom reasons in the work item for each State.

I am afraid there is no such way to add **some custom reasons** in the work item for **each State**.

Although we can use custom fields and custom rules, it can **only achieve one state for one reason**.

That because Azure devops not allowed to have multiple rules with the same action type using the same conditions:

[image]

And on the other hand, we also could not add a list as value of Picklist items:

[image]

So, I do not believe we could add some custom **reasonS** in the work item for each State at this moment.

You could add your request for adding a list as value of Picklist items on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any news here. As workaround, you can:

1. Add a new custom field with a pick list with reasons and mark it as required. [Add a picklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-picklist).
2. Use rules to set default values into your new field for each state transitions. [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops).